# Selecting row max value using SQL LIKE operator

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the row of max value  using MAX() function and with SQL LIKE operator in SQL.

```
Table
ID | meta_key      | meta_value
---------------------------------
1  |best_score_1   |     10       
1  |best_score_2   |     20       
1  |best_score_3   |     30       
1  |best_score_4   |     40
```

Here is my sql

```
SELECT MAX(meta_value), meta_key FROM Table WHERE meta_key LIKE '%\_best_score%'
```

It displays the correct max value, the problem is that, the meta_key displaying is wrong, the output should be best_score_4 and 40, but it produces best_score_1  and 40. 
I wonder which part am I missing?

Comment: I'm guessing `WHERE LIKE` is a typo and it originally is `WHERE meta_key LIKE` otherwise it would throw an error...

Comment: oh yes, sorry It was typo.. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an `ORDER BY` with a `LIMIT 1` in this case:

```
SELECT meta_value, meta_key
FROM Table
WHERE meta_key LIKE '%best_score%'
ORDER BY meta_value DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: is this working on mysql? I'm getting errors on sql syntax. 
I did search about TOP 1 and it is on the documentation.

Comment: I figured it out, I need to used LIMIT instead of TOP

Comment: @JamesBlond: You may have to add `DESC` after `ORDER BY meta_value`